# Can't send_keys to td in selenium python (no input tag available)

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I can find the element and click on it:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tinymce']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]").click()
```

When I try to send_keys to it with:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tinymce']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]").send_keys("test")
```

I get

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jlesslar\Documents\Scripts\post robot automater.py", line 60, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tinymce']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]").send_keys("test")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.81)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

As far as I cant tell the td is where I want to send_keys to but online it says I should either have a text field or input tag available to me for send_keys to work (which I do not)

[image]

Guidance would be much appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the innerHTML value by using a JS using execute_script()

First get your element:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tinymce']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]")
```

Then try by setting directly the innerHTML value:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerHTML = "test";', el)
```